How to revoke access to a document using an Azure App Registration secret/certificate
Using the C# wrapper of the MIP SDK I've been trying to protect documents and revoke access to documents. Protection and revocation both work fine when the JWT token is retrieved through an PublicClientApplication using the username and password of an Office account with an Office 365 license (both in the File and Protection component). However, when I try to revoke access to a document using an Azure App Registration secret/certificate the following exception is thrown:
...
Microsoft.InformationProtection.Exceptions.NoPermissionsException: Received message User has no right to revoke the document. 
User doesn't have premium license. when targeting https://api.aadrm.com/my/v2/publishedpolicies/revoke, 
NoPermissionsError.Category=NotPremiumLicenseUser, 
...

The token returned from the following PublicClientApplication code in combination with different App Registration API permissions works fine:
// Snippets of the IAuthDelegate implementation
...
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
            .Build();

var result = app
               .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, config.Username, config.Password)
               .ExecuteAsync();

return result.AccessToken;
...

However, when I use the a secret, in combination with different combinations of API permissions, the exception from earlier is thrown.
// Snippets of the IAuthDelegate implementation
...
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithClientSecret(config.Secret)
            .Build();

var result = app
               .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
               .ExecuteAsync();

return result.AccessToken;
...

Is there a specific combination of API permissions and configuration in the SDK that I am missing or is it simply not possible to revoke access to a document (using the MIP SDK) with an secret/certificate?

The user account associated with the Azure App Registration must have a Microsoft 365 compliance license that includes Azure Information Protection (AIP) Premium. Without this license, the user will not have the rights needed to perform revocation.

Check the permissions for both the Azure Rights Management Service and the Microsoft Purview Information Protection Sync Service. Ensure that tenant-wide admin consent has been granted for the application permissions required by your app. This is crucial for accessing certain features of the MIP SDK.

Hi @Rukmini , I can perform revocation just fine using a user account, however I would like to perform revocation using a secret/certificate associate with the App Registration. Either through just a secret or by using a secret and by specifying a delegated user, I would like to perform revocation. Is that possible?
Ideally, I would like to perform the MSAL authentication without using the ROPC (username/password) flow.

Make use of client credential flow or any other delegated flow

The issue is, like it I stated in my post, that the code for the client credential flow throws a Microsoft.InformationProtection.Exceptions.NoPermissionsException with the message Received message User has no right to revoke the document. when revoking access to a file.
